# How to overwrite historical revisions of a file with latest revision in git?

Tags: git, github

Kind of a strange question, but here is my scenario: I have accidentally added an SVG image with a large embedded PNG into git, committed, and pushed. Yesterday I noticed the issue and fixed it by removing the embedded PNG, so the size of that image went from 1500kb to 35kb. The problem I have is that I don't need the historical version anymore (which takes up 1500kb of space), but I DO need an image to be present (the updated one) in those old revisions. So I don't want to necessarily just delete the history of the image as I want old revisions to still work - what I want is to push the new version backwards in time to when I committed the original revision, so that it is as if I had never committed the larger file, just the smaller correct one right off the bat in the past. Is this possible to do?

I am aslo using github to host the repository and will need to push the updated entire history - is this easy to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't yet pushed your repository to anyone else, you can do this easily with `git rebase -i`. Mark the relevant commit for editing, and then replace the image file as needed.

[See the docs for more details](http://book.git-scm.com/4_interactive_rebasing.html).

You can use the `-f` option to `git push` which will force your edited history to overwrite that on Github. Be aware that this may make things a bit messy for anyone else who has pulled the repository, though.

Comment: Thanks, this does seem to do what I want, but others have already pulled after I pushed (the mistake was from several months ago). I guess I'll just leave it be for now, but in the future it's nice to know this works and I should review my additions better before pushing up.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need to do a quite messy operation involving cherrypicking, rebasing, and general git wizardry.

I really wouldn't worry about it. Leave it as it is. It only means you'll download some extra kilobytes once every time the repo is cloned. Otherwise you're only pushing and pulling tiny diff's anyway....